# Can not open ftp port via firewalld

Tags: centos7, firewalld

I'm trying to open ftp port in the public zone and firewall-cmd exits with a very non-descriptive response.
Command output is:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=ftp
Error: COMMAND_FAILED
```

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

---

Updating original question with more details.

journalctl output:

```
~ firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=ftp
Error: COMMAND_FAILED
~ journalctl -xf
Mar 06 00:46:42 hostname firewalld[3496]: ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED
```

debug output:

```
~ firewalld --nofork --debug=10
<...>
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG1: zone.addService('public', 'ftp', 0)
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG4: <class 'firewall.core.fw_transaction.FirewallZoneTransaction'>.execute(True)
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG4: <class 'firewall.core.fw_transaction.FirewallZoneTransaction'>.prepare(True, ...)
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG4: <class 'firewall.core.fw_transaction.FirewallZoneTransaction'>.prepare(True, ...)
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG4: <class 'firewall.core.fw_transaction.FirewallZoneTransaction'>.pre()
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG2: <class 'firewall.core.ipXtables.ip4tables'>: /usr/sbin/iptables-restore /run/firewalld/temp.tptEtP: 89
       1: *filter
       2: -A IN_public_allow -p tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
       3: COMMIT
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG2: <class 'firewall.core.ipXtables.ip6tables'>: /usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore /run/firewalld/temp.CYsjiA: 89
       1: *filter
       2: -A IN_public_allow -p tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
       3: COMMIT
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG2: <class 'firewall.core.modules.modules'>: /sbin/modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG2: <class 'firewall.core.ipXtables.ip4tables'>: /usr/sbin/iptables-restore /run/firewalld/temp.1dBrUZ: 89
       1: *filter
       2: -D IN_public_allow -p tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
       3: COMMIT
2017-03-06 00:49:57 DEBUG2: <class 'firewall.core.ipXtables.ip6tables'>: /usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore /run/firewalld/temp.vbUyZC: 89
       1: *filter
       2: -D IN_public_allow -p tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
       3: COMMIT
2017-03-06 00:49:57 ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED
```

One more update: if I do:

```
~ iptables -A IN_public_allow -p tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

ftp service is working. However I'd like to manage everything via firewalld. So I'm wondering if it is a firewalld glitch or error in configuration.

Comment: You may find more information in the journal.

Comment: Unfortunately firewalld log and even 'firewalld --nofork --debug=10' provide the same brief error: COMMAND_FAILED

Comment: are you root? 
is this a virtual server or bare metal? this might be related to limits of the guest.
you might want to read https://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-get-started-firewalld/ which seems to describe the process as well

Comment: I am root. Server is a virtual machine. I can successfully open any other ports except ftp.

Comment: What is the underlying hypervisor? if it is OpenVZ then you will not be able to control the firewall. if it's not then as Michael suggested, look in the journal.

Comment: KVM. The only thing I see in journal is: "firewalld[3493]: ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED".

Comment: `journalctl -xf` will show more about the error. Since `firewalld` runs `iptables` commands in the background, you most probably are missing the appropriate table where the `ftp` service is going to.

Comment: Updated the original question with more debug info.

Comment: Hm, now that's interesting. What happened to your kernel? You don't seem to be running the standard CentOS kernel.

Comment: Not sure how to tell whats happened. Standard yum update. Did nothing extra. And yum updates worked before.

Comment: You completely ignored my question. Please go back, read it and respond.

Comment: Your question was "What happened to your kernel?", I've written "Standard yum update.". Nothing else. Could you please elaborate what other info you need?

Comment: I am have the same problem on bare metal.  Kernel 3.10.0-514.21.1.el7 I noticed that FTP opens ports 20 and 21, and loads module nf_conntrack_ftp.  modprobe -v nf_contrack_ftp reveals could not insert, cannot allocate memory.  This system has 8 GB of memory with 1 GB and 4 GB swap partitions available.  Solution: it was out of memory because the database was started first.  I shutdown the database and the kernel module slipped right in.  Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue, but --add-port worked for me:

```
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=21/tcp
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work for me - I am unable to load nf_conntrack_ftp.  Is 8 GB of RAM not enough to open FTP ports for firewalld?  Also, when I modprobe -v nf_conntrack_ftp I get the error - not enough memory to load, unloading.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the problem of LXC guest with host that supports it. Does your LXC support this?

Host needs to have support
modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
lsmod shows nf_conntrack_ftp?
if so add nf_conntrack_ftp to /etc/modules
Capture the output of modinfo nf_conntrack_ftp for later

Supported in your LXC?
/sys/module/nf_conntrack_ftp exists?
/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper exists?
mkdir -p /lib/modules/4.4.67-1-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/ replace 4.4.67-1-pve with your host, I'm using Proxmox with that kernel.
touch all those .ko files from the host
put the output of modinfo nf_conntrack_ftp into the nf_conntrack_ftp.ko file
backup modinfo
replace it with this script

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /lib/modules/4.4.67-1-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/$1.ko
```

Replace the path with what you created earlier. Make the file executable. You want modinfo nf_conntrack_ftp to have the same output from your host as in your guest.

Next we need to replace modprobe with the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
```

Make it executable as well. Because this is the guest it's not like you even have modules to probe.

Great. You can now fool /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firewall/functions.py that your guest can do things with modinfo.

You are also fooling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/firewall/core/modules.py with the modprobe replacement.

Again, I feel it's ok that modinfo and modprobe is replaced with these fake scripts because the guest in a container doesn't have access to modules anyway. This fact is why it doesn't work.

I also think that the firewalld project should fix this as it seems like an unintended bug.